# MySQL - When Command column in Processlist shows "Prepare" or "execute"

Tags: mysql

Can someone please highlight when a "Command" shows "Prepare" or "Execute" for "Show Full Processlist"

Any example which shows this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The command status you refer to is pretty self explanatory:

1) The thread is preparing a statement, for example when the following:

```
PREPARE STATEMENT my_stmt FROM 'SELECT * FROM countries WHERE id = ?';
```

2) The thread ist executing a formerly prepared statement:

```
EXECUTE my_stmt;
```

You can also refer to the documentation: [Thread Command Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

Comment: I have tried this already but still 'Show Full Processlist' "Command" column output shows query instead of "Prepare" or "Execute"